# ASP.NET button set enabled but page shows disabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a web page on which one can select a report and a printer to which to print, and then choose to print the report with a button. The button should be disabled until both a report and printer are selected. I use this to do so:

```
    Protected Sub PrintButtonUseability()
        btnPrint.Enabled = ddlPrinters.SelectedText.Length > 0 AndAlso rgWebReports.SelectedIndexes.Count > 0
    End Sub
```

Debugging indicates it is being set properly. But if I select something from `ddlPrinters` and then select something from `rgWebReports`, it turns out that, even though stepping through the code that `btnPrint.Enabled` is set to `False`, the button is disabled! Strangely, if I select from `rgWebReports` first and then select from `ddlPrinters` then it works as expected.

Additional information that seemed irrelevant was that I'm using a `RadAjaxManager` to clearly show the page is busy when retrieving data, especially when selecting a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, as I was about to post this question, I had a suspicion: maybe the delay somehow caused something to go haywire. Here is my `RadAjaxManager`:

```html
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ddlPrinters">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlPrint" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btnPrint" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgWebReports" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

For some reason, removing the `btnPrint` and `rgWebReports` resolved my issue, and it works correctly. I am at a loss to explain exactly **why** it works, though.